# Python Pandas - unique combinations of variables in multiple specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, unique, reshape

I am trying to get unique combinations of phone numbers and values, where phone numbers and values are each in two potential columns.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'phone1':[4567890876, 4567890876, 9178889999, 3237800876],
                   'phone2':[4567890876, 4567890876, 9178889999, 2139990000],
                   'num1':[1,2,3,3],
                   'num2':[5,2,3,1]})
```

The unique values would look like:

```
phone         num
4567890876    1
4567890876    2
4567890876    5
9178889999    3
2139990000    1
2139990000    3
3237800876    1
3237800876    3
```

I found two ways to do this but they both feel very clumsy/wrong:

1) Copying the df four times (phone1/num1, phone1/num2, phone2/num1, phone2/num2), concatenating, and dropping duplicates

2) Indexing by the phone fields, stacking, then indexing by the number fields and stacking again, and dropping duplicates

If anyone has better/cleaner/faster ideas, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why `2139990000` and `3237800876` appear twice in the resulting DF?

Answer (score 2):

[`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) can coalesce multiple columns into one value column (and one variable column). You could use it once to coalesce the `num1` and `num2` columns, and an second time to coalesce the `phone1` and `phone2` columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'phone1':[4567890876, 4567890876, 9178889999, 3237800876],
                   'phone2':[4567890876, 4567890876, 9178889999, 2139990000],
                   'num1':[1,2,3,3],
                   'num2':[5,2,3,1]})

melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['phone1', 'phone2'], var_name='numvar', value_name='num')
melted = pd.melt(melted, id_vars=['numvar', 'num'], value_name='phone')
melted = melted[['num', 'phone']]
melted = melted.drop_duplicates()
print(melted)
```

yields

```
    num       phone
0     1  4567890876
1     2  4567890876
2     3  9178889999
3     3  3237800876
4     5  4567890876
7     1  3237800876
11    3  2139990000
15    1  2139990000
```

---

**Explanation**: Use `id_vars` to prevent the `phone1` and `phone2` columns from being melted. Below shows the result of melting the `num1` and `num2` columns:

```
In [166]: melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['phone1', 'phone2'], var_name='numvar', value_name='num'); melted
Out[166]: 
       phone1      phone2 numvar  num
0  4567890876  4567890876   num1    1
1  4567890876  4567890876   num1    2
2  9178889999  9178889999   num1    3
3  3237800876  2139990000   num1    3
4  4567890876  4567890876   num2    5
5  4567890876  4567890876   num2    2
6  9178889999  9178889999   num2    3
7  3237800876  2139990000   num2    1
```

Then apply `pd.melt` again to combine the `phone1` and `phone2` columns into one:

```
In [168]: pd.melt(melted, id_vars=['numvar', 'num'], value_name='phone')
Out[168]: 
   numvar  num variable       phone
0    num1    1   phone1  4567890876
1    num1    2   phone1  4567890876
2    num1    3   phone1  9178889999
3    num1    3   phone1  3237800876
4    num2    5   phone1  4567890876
5    num2    2   phone1  4567890876
6    num2    3   phone1  9178889999
7    num2    1   phone1  3237800876
8    num1    1   phone2  4567890876
9    num1    2   phone2  4567890876
10   num1    3   phone2  9178889999
11   num1    3   phone2  2139990000
12   num2    5   phone2  4567890876
13   num2    2   phone2  4567890876
14   num2    3   phone2  9178889999
15   num2    1   phone2  2139990000
```

Drop duplicates, and drop the `numvar` and `variable` columns and you get the desired result (albeit in a different order).

Comment: What is wrong with you first solution - `lreshape()`? I liked it more :)

Comment: @MaxU: `pd.lreshape(df, {'phone':['phone1', 'phone2'], 'num':['num1','num2']}).drop_duplicates()` has the right form but gives the wrong result. It works as though it concatenates the `phone1` and `phone2` columns, and similarly for the `num1` and `num2` columns, but it does not associate `num1` with *both* `phone1` and `phone2` nor associate `num2` with both `phone` columns. It only associateds `num1` with `phone1` and `num2` with `phone2`.